# Show that the sequence $nxe^{-nx^2}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a,\infty)$ for every $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the sequence $nxe^{-nx^2}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a,\infty)$ for every $a>0$

> Q) Show that the sequence $nxe^{-nx^2}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a,\infty)$ for every $a>0$.

I know it does not converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ since maximum of the sequence is $\sqrt{n/2e}$ when $x=\sqrt{1/2n}$

but I confuse that why maximum is $nae^{-na^2}$ on $[a,\infty)$

Intuitively, If a is bigger then $\sqrt{1/2n}$ then it is a decreasing sequence, so maximum is $f_n(a)$

what if a is smaller then $\sqrt{1/2n}$? maybe since it is countable, it doesn't matter.

But I'm trouble in taking in mathmatics symbols.

any help plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is basically the solution. In order to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ (on $[a, \infty)$), you have to prove that given any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $N$ such that $|f_n(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$ and $x \in [a, \infty)$.

So let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given.

Take $N_1$ big enough so that $\sqrt{1 / 2N_1} < a$. Then for all $n \ge N_1$ we have $\sqrt{1 / 2n} < a$; in particular, as you said, the maximum of $f_n$ (for these $n$) is at $a$, so that we know:
$$|f_n(x)| \le f_n(a) = na e^{-na^2} \quad \text{for all $n \ge N_1$ and all $x \in [a, \infty)$}$$
We also know that $na e^{-na^2}$ converges to $0$ for $n \to \infty$. Thus, there is an $N_2$ such that
$$na e^{-na^2} < \varepsilon \quad \text{for all $n \ge N_2$}$$
Combining these two statements, we get:
$$|f_n(x)| \le f_n(a) < \varepsilon \quad \text{for all $n \ge \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ and all $x \in [a, \infty)$}.$$
So by taking $N := \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ we are done.

Comment: I really appreciate it